# Loop through Object 2 values to find if it match with Object 1 min variable

Tags: algorithm, loops, object, data-structures, match

So i am really stuck with this exercise for a few hours. The idea is to find the friends name who is also studying the weakest subject. I have this piece of code here:

```
    const reportCard = {
  Biology: 85,
  English: 75,
  Economics: 90,
  History: 67,
  Philosophy: 98,
};


const subjects = {
  Dylan: 'Biology',
  Jen: 'English',
  Emily: 'Economics',
  Amy: 'History',
  Lenny: 'Philosophy',

};

console.log(studyBuddy(reportCard, subjects));
```

I have implemented a min variable to find the lowest grades in first object like so:

```
val = Object.values(reportCard)
    const min = Math.min(...val)
```

How can i match the second object values with the first one that match the min variable. Is it anyway that i can implement that?
I just want a hint i don't want that somebody to solve it for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  This is a standard technique in sorting and searching, covered in many tutorials and texts.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you without actually solving the task.
I would first take keys of the friends object, go through them and use as a key to access reportCard object. Let me give you a quick example:

```
const studentNames = Object.keys(subjects); // all student names
studentNames.forEach(student => {
    const subjectValue = reportCard[student]; // now you have the value for every student
});
```

Assuming the max value for subject is 100, you can define variable equal to 101 at first step, and check it in the loop if any of the student has less value. I hope that will help.

Comment: I implemented it like this @kirill.buga :
 `const studyBuddy = (reportCard, subjects) => {
    val = Object.values(reportCard)
    const min = Math.min(...val)
    const weakestSubject = Object.keys(reportCard).find(key => reportCard[key] === min);
  for (let val in subjects){
     if (subjects[val] === weakestSubject){
       return val
     } else {
       return 'Me'
    }
  }
     };`

Comment: The challenge criteria is actually to return the friends name, else to return string 'Me'. I don't know why it is returning me? When i delete the else statement it actually returns the right name. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like this:

```
const studyBuddy = (reportCard, subjects) => {
  // Write code here
    val = Object.values(reportCard)
    const min = Math.min(...val)
    const weakestSubject = Object.keys(reportCard).find(key => reportCard[key] === min);

   for (let val in subjects){
     if (subjects[val] === weakestSubject){
       return val
     } else {
       return 'Me'
    }
  }
     };
```

The challenge criteria is actually to return the friends name, else to return string 'Me'. I don't know why it is returning me? When i delete the else statement it actually returns the right name. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to get the weakest subject name from the object 'reportCard'; you can loop through the object, mark the subject which has the lowest marks.
Now, after getting the lowest marks from the object 'reportCard', again loop through the second object 'subjects' to check who is assigned to the subject, which has lowest marks we obtained by a loop through the object 'reportCard'.

```
const reportCard = {
 Biology: 85,
 English: 75,
 Economics: 90,
 History: 67,
 Philosophy: 98,
};


const subjects = {
    Dylan: 'Biology',
   Jen: 'English',
  Emily: 'Economics',
  Amy: 'History',
  Lenny: 'Philosophy',
 };

function studyBuddy(reportCard, subjects){
var weakestSubjectName = null;
var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;

for(var key in reportCard){
    // check every marks whether it is lowest than the prev lowest marks or not
    // if so, assign the subject name which has currently lowest marks
    if(reportCard[key] < min){
        min = reportCard[key];
        weakestSubjectName = key;
    }
}
// now you can loop through the second object, to get the name of person/friend who's studying the subject
 for(var key in subjects){
        if(subjects[key] === weakestSubjectName) return key;
 }
 return null;
}
 console.log(studyBuddy(reportCard, subjects));
```